# Multiplicity of real numbers in a tuple with known cardinality decidable?

Tags: logic, computability, constructive-mathematics

Given a tuple $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ of computable real numbers $x_1, \ldots ,x_n$ and its cardinality $|\{x_1, \ldots x_n\}|=d \leq n$, is it decidable which numbers have which multiplicity? In other words, can we decide whether $x_i=x_j$, for $ i, j = 1, ...,n$ with $i\neq j$ ?

[Here](http://cca-net.de/vasco/publications/spectral.ps) is the origin of this question:

[image]

Comment: I think you mean a "multiset" or a "tuple" rather than a "set". Sets, by the axiom of extensionality, ignore duplicates.

Comment: Basically you are asking if it is decidable whether 2 given computable functions are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if we just enumerate and check the $n$ computable approximations $(A_k(x_1),\cdots,A_k(x_n))$ of $(x_1, \cdots x_n)$ up to an error of $\frac 1 {10^k}$ iterating on $k$?

As an example we may have:

- step 0: $\|(1.1,1.8,1,1,4,5)-(x_1,\ldots,x_6)\|_\infty\leq 1$

So we conclude that that $x_5$ and $x_6$ are different from the other ones and we have two groups $(x_1,...,x_4)$ and $(x_5,x_6)$ that have a distance of $1$ at lest so that we can be sure that $x_i\neq x_j$ for $i=1,\cdots ,4$ and $j=5,6$. If $d=2$ we are done otherwise we continue:

- step 1: $\|(1.58,1.57,1,1,4,5.41)-(x_1,\ldots,x_6)\|_\infty\leq 0.1$

Now we can see four groups: $(x_1,x_2)$, $(x_3,x_4)$, $(x_5)$, $(x_6)$. If $d=4$ we are done, otherwise we continue with the error $0.01$.

- step 2: $\ldots$

If $m$ is the minimum distance between the $d$ distinct numbers (that we don't know) we will have $10^{-k}<m$ at the step $k>\log_{10}(m)$ where we will see exactly $d$ different groups. We don't know $m$ but will know that we have finished because we know the number $d$ in advance.

Comment: @ValerySaharov But the point is that - *under the assumption that there are exactly $d$ distinct elements* - this loop is guaranteed to terminate! That is, we're imagining at the outset that we know (somehow) the number of distinct reals; we then run the algorithm Marco describes until we see $d$-many groups of elements. We know that at some point we will see that many, because there are in fact $d$-many distinct reals - conversely, once we see $d$ many blocks, we know we've found them all, so we stop. The key point is that $d$ is being used as a parameter in this construction.

Comment: Why can't I decide the condition for the while loop? Isn't it clear that this algorithm would stop for any input?

Comment: As far as I know in order to be decidable for a problem it is just required an "effective method" to solve it, it doesn't matter how you prove/know that the method is effective

Comment: @ValerySaharov "Constructively" is not the same as "effectively." I believe Ziegler/Brattka style computable analysis takes place in a classical background. Note that even classically, the "comparison loop" for telling if two reals are the same will **not** terminate if they *are* the same - which is why real equality is co-semidecidable but not decidable. The background logic is classical.

Comment: It seems to me that there cannot be any 'a priori' upper bound to the number of operations that may be needed to distinguish the groups of numbers *for any algotithm*: the functions that define the numbers could in principle give identical outputs for arbitrary large inputs and you cannot avoid testing all of them in sequence

Comment: @ValerySaharov Yup, that happens a lot in computability theory.

Answer (score 1):

No. This isn't possible even if $n = 2$.

"Computable" means "we can approximate the number to within any desired precision by a finite terminating algorithm".
There's a [MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40618/uncomputability-of-the-identity-relation-on-computable-real-numbers) which states that equality of computable numbers is not decidable, by using it to decide whether an arbitrary Turing machine halts.

---

(My original answer, which OP correctly pointed out was nonsense).

Yes. The following algorithm will work:

```
list = {}
for i=1 to n
  for j=i+1 to n
    if x[i] == x[j]: add (i, j) to list
return list
```

By the Church-Turing thesis, there is a Turing machine which does the above.

Comment: @ValerySaharov Oh dear, that was embarrassing. Sorry. I'll edit my answer. (This is what happens when I answer questions immediately after waking up.)